# How to use selected file from previously defined method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've defined a method inside of a class using askopenfilename to select a file:

```
def file(self):

    options = {
       'defaultextension': '.txt',
       'filetypes': [('text files', '.txt')]
  }

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose a file', initialdir="/", **options)

    if filename:
      directory = os.path.split(filename)[-1]
      self.var.set(directory)
```

I'd like to use the selected file to run against another method to run a quick text analysis. I tried using:

```
text = file.filename
```

but this gives me the error "'function' object has no attribute 'filename'" even though it is defined in my method. I figured that because I'm defining both things in a class that it would be able to recognise "filename" that is defined in the method file(). Why doesn't it recognise this?

Comment: 'filename' is a local variable within the method; it ceases to exist the moment the method returns.  Use 'self.filename' to store the value in the class instance so you can refer to it later.

Comment: ... or return the filename variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems like filename is a local variable in the method file() and isn't assigned as a member variable to the object itself?  Perhaps you should change your definition:

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose a file', initialdir="/", **options)
```

to

```
 self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose a file', initialdir="/", **options)
```

And make those changes to the rest of your method body.

Alternatively you can simply return filename at the end of the method.

Here's a simple working example where I return filename (I got rid of the self.var.set part and I also am using python2 so I changed filedialog to tkFileDialog):

```
import tkFileDialog
import os

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Initialized')

    def file(self):
        options = {
       'defaultextension': '.txt',
       'filetypes': [('text files', '.txt')]
        }

        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose a file', initialdir="/", **options)

        if filename:
            directory = os.path.split(filename)[-1]
            return filename

newTest = Test()
filename = newTest.file()
print filename
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like this is the obvious issue, but I tried both of your suggestions and unfortunately I'm still getting the errors "'filename' is not defined" or "function has no attribute 'filename'".. Also, for some reason when I tried using "self.filename" it gave me the error: "name 'self' is not defined" for some reason even though I want to define "text" inside of my class..